# Spring batch: multithread step misconfiguration

Tags: spring-batch, hikaricp

These is my step:

```java
@Bean
public Step autors(
    ItemReader<Autor> autorItemReader,
    AutorMappingItemProcessor processor,
    AutorPipeliningItemWriter unitatPipeliningWriter
) {
    return this.stepBuilderFactory
        .get("autors")
        .<Autor, AutorDenormalized>chunk(100)
        .reader(autorItemReader)
        .processor(processor)
        .writer(unitatPipeliningWriter)
        .build();
}
```

It's working very well.

Now, I need to be processed bt "chuck dedicated threads".

I've added this configuration:

```java
@Bean
public Step autors(
    ItemReader<Autor> autorItemReader,
    AutorMappingItemProcessor processor,
    AutorPipeliningItemWriter unitatPipeliningWriter,
    TaskExecutor taskExecutor
) {
    return this.stepBuilderFactory
        .get("autors")
        .<Autor, AutorDenormalized>chunk(100)
        .reader(autorItemReader)
        .processor(processor)
        .writer(unitatPipeliningWriter)
        .taskExecutor(taskExecutor)
        .throttleLimit(4)
        .build();
}

@Bean
public TaskExecutor taskExecutor() {
    return new SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor("spring_batch");
}
```

Problem arises here, since I'm getting those kind of messages:

```
HikariPool-2 - Connection ConnectionID:1 ClientConnectionId: 8bee2b6e-d88e-4831-b9e5-163b52dca86c marked as broken because of SQLSTATE(08S01), ErrorCode(0)

com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The connection is closed.
```

Or

```
HikariPool-2 - Connection ConnectionID:1 ClientConnectionId: 8bee2b6e-d88e-4831-b9e5-163b52dca86c marked as broken because of SQLSTATE(08S01), ErrorCode(0)

com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The TDS protocol stream is not valid.
```

My related `ItemReader` is:

```java
@Bean
public ItemReader<Autor> autorReader() {
    String sql = "select * from ...";

    JdbcCursorItemReader<Autor> jdbcCursorItemReader = new JdbcCursorItemReader<>();
    jdbcCursorItemReader.setDataSource(this.dataSource);
    jdbcCursorItemReader.setSql(sql);
    jdbcCursorItemReader.setVerifyCursorPosition(false);
    jdbcCursorItemReader.setRowMapper(this.autorMapper);

    return jdbcCursorItemReader;
}
```

My datasource is:

```java
@Bean
@JobDataSource
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.job-datasource")
public DataSource jobDataSource() {
    return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
}
```

And properties:

```
spring.job-datasource.jdbcUrl=jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;databaseName=ac_img_p
spring.job-datasource.username=sa
spring.job-datasource.password=StR0nGp4ss.
spring.job-datasource.driverClassName=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
spring.job-datasource.initialization-mode=always
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The `JdbcCursorItemReader` is not thread-safe as it extends `AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader` which is [not thread-safe](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.3.x/api/org/springframework/batch/item/support/AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.html). So using it in a multi-threaded step is not correct. What you can do is decorate it with a `SynchronizedItemStreamReader`:

```
@Bean
public SynchronizedItemStreamReader<Autor> autorReader() {
   String sql = "select * from ...";

   JdbcCursorItemReader<Autor> jdbcCursorItemReader = new JdbcCursorItemReader<>();
   jdbcCursorItemReader.setDataSource(this.dataSource);
   jdbcCursorItemReader.setSql(sql);
   jdbcCursorItemReader.setVerifyCursorPosition(false);
   jdbcCursorItemReader.setRowMapper(this.autorMapper);

   SynchronizedItemStreamReader<Autor> synchronizedReader = new SynchronizedItemStreamReader<>();
   synchronizedReader.setDelegate(jdbcCursorItemReader)
   return synchronizedReader;
}
```

Otherwise, you can use a thread-safe reader like the `JdbcPagingItemReader`.

As a side note, your `autorReader` method should return the actual type or at least `ItemStreamReader<Autor>` so that Spring Batch correctly proxies your reader.